# Method threw 'org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException' exception. detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables ( i.e, Entities in Hibernate) which are related as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_one")
public class TableOne  {

    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String value;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name= "code")
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }

    @Column(name= "value")
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    // setters ignored here
}

----------------------------------------------
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_two")
public class TableTwo {

    private Integer id;
    private TableOne tableOne;
    private String request;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_one_id", nullable = false)
    public TableOne getTableOne() {
        return tableOne;
    }

    @Column(name= "request")
    public String getRequest() {
        return this.request;
    }
    // setters ignored here
}
```

Now, from a method (or a class) which does not have `@Transactional` annotation, I call a Service class method to persist `TableTwo` object. This service method is annotated `@Transactional`.

```
// from a normal method with no annotations
service.insert(tableTwo);
----------------------------
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao dao;

    @Transactional
    public void insert(TableTwo tableTwo){
        dao.insert(tableTwo);
    }
}
------------------------------
public class MyDao {
    public void insert(TableTwo tableTwo){
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(tableTwo.getTableOne());
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(tabletwo);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following exception in debugging:

```
Method threw 'org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException' exception.
detached entity passed to persist: org.project.TableOne
```

What is wrong here ? I am converting the transient object of `TableOne` inside `TableTwo` to persisted state, and then persisting `TableTwo` object. How can I correct this ? Is it possible to do so through annotation, if possible ?

I don't want to be persisting `TableOne` object every time I persist `TableTwo` object. If possible, I just want to do :

```
tableTwo.setTableOne(new TableOne(id));
dao.persist(tableTwo);
```

Comment: Did you try with adding cascade attribute to `ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`.That way you don't need to save tableone entity explicitly.

Comment: Which cascade attribute : ALL, PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH ?

Comment: Since you are calling persist method, make sure the cascade attribute is PERSIST or ALL.

Comment: I ma still getting : org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: even after doing `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_one_id", nullable = false)
    public TableOne getTableOne() {
        return tableOne;
    }`

Comment: In fact,I am able persist the tableTwo and tableOne objects using your code as-it-is as well as with CascadeType.PERSIST. Can you post the code where you are creating tableTwo and tableOne objects before sending it to your service class.

Comment: TableOne tableOne = service.getTableOneById(id);
TableTwo tableTwo = new TableTwo();
tableTwo.setId(null);
tableTwo.setTableOne(tableOne);
tableTwo.setRequest("request");
service.insert(tableTwo);

Comment: I see that you are getting the `tableOne` object from service class i.e., `TableOne tableOne = service.getTableOneById(id);`. So I think that tableOne record already exists in the database and there is no need to persist it again in your dao method. You can remove `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(tableTwo.getTableOne());` and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are getting the `tableOne` object from service class i.e., `TableOne tableOne = service.getTableOneById(id);`.

So, I believe that `tableOne` record already exists in the database and subsequently there is no need to persist it again in your dao `insert(...)` method.

You can remove `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(tableTwo.getTableOne());` as you are not making any changes to the `tableOne` object.

Or in case you have made any changes to the `tableOne` object that needs to be persisted, then consider using merge method i.e., `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(tableTwo.getTableOne());` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `saveOrUpdate` instead of `persist`.
`persist` operation is intended for brand new transient objects and it fails if `id` is already assigned.

Comment: Do you mean on both parent and child objects ? `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(tableTwo.getTableOne()); sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(tabletwo);`

Comment: Try in both @OneMoreError